# XSLT if statement not matching properly

Tags: javascript, xslt

I am matching a XML data type and then selecting the corresponding records. I have it showing the selected data as required and got it to show in a JavaScript alert. However, when I do the if statement, it just matches everything in the XML document. Here is my XSLT

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:param name="customeroBeSelected" />
<xsl:template match="/myDataSet/Customers">
      <xsl:if test="CustomerNo = $customeroBeSelected"> 
           <xsl:value-of select="FirstName" />  
           <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
           <xsl:value-of select="Surname" />    
      </xsl:if> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its all working, but for some reason it seems to be looping for each customer.

```
  <myDataSet> 
      <customers> 
          <CustomerID>200</CustomerID> 
          <CustomerNo>SA124</CustomerNo> 
          <FirstName>Sally-Anne</FirstName> 
          <Surname>Adams</Surname> 
          <CreditLimit>300</CreditLimit> 
      </customers>

      <customers> 
          <CustomerID>201</CustomerID> 
          <CustomerNo>AS256</CustomerNo> 
          <FirstName>Anne</FirstName> 
          <Surname>Samuels</Surname> 
          <CreditLimit>1000</CreditLimit>
      </customers>

 </myDataSet>
```

I want to select the customer FirstName that corresponds with the CustomerNo. However, my if statement is selecting that and everything else.

Answer (score 2):

First problem is case of the `xsl:template` match expression, the xml element is lowercase; second is how you use your parameter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:param name="customeroBeSelected">SA124</xsl:param>
<xsl:template match="/myDataSet/customers">
      <xsl:if test="CustomerNo=$customeroBeSelected"> 
           <xsl:value-of select="FirstName" />  
           <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
           <xsl:value-of select="Surname" />    
      </xsl:if> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here to see it working:
http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/zuNNZT

Comment: Thank you. My match expression has been changed on here to be less identifiable. I used your version and it still changes the innerHTML of ever data set with every element in each set. I'm not sure why it isn't looking at the if statement?

Comment: @TomNagle happy to help. The if statement is not running because the xsl:template `match` is not matching... elements are case-sensitive (`c`ustomers). Please accept my answer if it worked.